# How to declare a function in Flow that changes arguments without ESLint errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, flowtype

I have both ESLint and Flow going in a CLI script and am struggling with how to tell Flow about a function that changes arguments in a way that ESLint will not complain.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// I define a dummy function that gets redefined later 
let debug = () => {}
// let debug = (msg?:string) => {}" // ESLint complains about unused vars

// Main function - in here debug gets defined based on some new data
const foo = () => {
  ...
  debug = (msg: string) => console.log(msg)

}
// Outside of the main func I still need to call it in a couple of places. 
debug('go') // Flow: Cannot call `debug` because no arguments are expected by function

const handleRejection = async err => {
  debug('error')
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', handleRejection)

// Run script (CLI)
foo()
```

The code works fine but I am wondering if there is a better way that will make ESLint and Flow happy.Right now I tell ESLint to ignore it.

Is there a proper fix?

Comment: reassigning debug itself seems like a bad idea ... what's `foo` really?

Comment: is there a point at which debug is actually used in its noop form? the example code you provide suggests there is no reason to declare the dummy form rather than the string -> [side effect] form initially

Comment: Any reason not to disable the ESLint warning in this case? The warnings are there to guide you, not to give you strict unbreakable rules.

Comment: @JonasWilms - its a CLI script - foo is the main fn called.

Comment: @PartyLich - its not used in noop and I can define it but then I need to make a dummy call to write to /dev/null or sometiing else I get other ESLint warnings.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - its what I am doing. I guess it made me ponder if my design could be improved upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to explicitly declare the type of `debug`, since the core issue here is that Flow can't tell that what the type should be, e.g.

```
let debug: (msg: string) => void = () => {};
```

or

```
type DebugFn = (msg: string) => void;
let debug: DebugFn = () => {};
```